# Javassist edit if statemnt

Tags: java, javassist

I have looked at [javassist tutorial](http://www.javassist.org/tutorial/tutorial2.html#alter) but I haven't found anything about editing control statemnts

#### Question

How do I turn

```java
if (cond1 && cond2) {
    // do stuff
}
```

into

```java
if ((cond1 && cond2) || (mynewcond)) {
    // do same stuff
}
```